# Why the internal energy can be written as $dU=TdS + HdB$?

Tags: thermodynamics

I thought it should be $dU = TdS + \dfrac{1}{2}BdH +\dfrac{1}{2}HdB$, because the magnetic energy density is $$\dfrac{1}{2\mu}B^2=\dfrac{1}{2}HB$$

Comment: Are B and H the magnetic induction and magnetic field, or are they exergy and enthalpy?

Comment: B and H are magnetic induction and magnetic field, respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if $B = \mu H$ and $\mu$ is constant ($d \mu =0$), then what you wrote is actually identical to your expression in the title.